# Basic drawing with Quartz 2D on iPhone

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

My goal is to make a program that will draw points whenever the screen is touched. This is what I have so far:

The header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ElSimView : UIView 
{
  CGPoint firstTouch;
  CGPoint lastTouch;
  UIColor *pointColor;
  CGRect *points;
  int npoints;
}

@property CGPoint firstTouch;
@property CGPoint lastTouch;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *pointColor;
@property CGRect *points;
@property int npoints;

@end
```

The implementation file:

```
//@synths etc.

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    return self;
}


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
  if(self = [super initWithCoder:coder])
  {
    self.npoints = 0;
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  firstTouch = [touch locationInView:self];
  lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self];  
  points = (CGRect *)malloc(sizeof(CGRect) * ++npoints);
  points[npoints-1] = CGRectMake(lastTouch.x-15, lastTouch.y-15,30,30);
  [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self];  
  [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, pointColor.CGColor);

  for(int i=0; i<npoints; i++)
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, points[i]);
  CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
}


- (void)dealloc {
    free(points);
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

When I load this and click some points, it draws the first points normally, then then next points are drawn along with random ellipses (not even circles).

Also I have another question: When is *exactly* `drawRect` executed?

Comment: drawRect is called when the view first loads and when u call setNeedsDisplay

Comment: Beyond the -drawRect: question, what is your exact question here?  Stack Overflow isn't designed for code review, but to answer specific questions.

Comment: The general question is: "Why doesn't it work?". The more specific question is "Where should I put the part where new points are added to make it work"?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I see what you were having problems with now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In -touchesEnded:withEvent:, you have the following code:

```
points = (CGRect *)malloc(sizeof(CGRect) * ++npoints);
points[npoints-1] = CGRectMake(lastTouch.x-15, lastTouch.y-15,30,30);
```

You are re-allocating an array for `points`, but not copying over any of your previous points.  This was causing you to use random uninitialized memory values instead of your saved CGRects.  Instead, try something like the following:

```
CGRect *newPoints = (CGRect *)malloc(sizeof(CGRect) * ++npoints);
for (unsigned int currentPoint = 0; currentPoint < (npoints - 1); currentPoint++)
{
    newPoints[currentPoint] = points[currentPoint];
}
free(points);
points = newPoints;

points[npoints-1] = CGRectMake(lastTouch.x-15, lastTouch.y-15,30,30);
```

You were also leaking the `points` array before by not freeing it before allocating a new array for its contents.

As far as when `-drawRect:` is called, it is triggered when the iPhone OS display system needs to recache the content of a UIView.  As Daniel stated, this typically happens once on initial display and whenever you manually call `-setNeedsDisplay` on the UIView.